# How can I force the newest dependency to be used by gradle

Tags: java, gradle, checkmarx

I’m attempting to upgrade an app I manage to satisfy a Checkmarx vulnerability scan. The scan is showing I am using an out of date version of org.apache.ivy and the issue is via Maven. To fix this I’ve I’ve added

```
all {
resolutionStrategy {
  force ‘org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.2’
}
}
```

If I run gradlew dependencies I only see the 2.5.2 version show in the tree as I expect. When I submit the build to Jenkins and have the Checkmarx scan run, it still shows that the older version of Ivy is present in the gradle cache path. What can I do to force only the newest version there?

Comment: If you are using both Maven and Gradle, you might need to update the pom.xml as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in dependencies block :

```
dependencies {
  //...
  implementation('org.apache.ivy:ivy') {
    version {
      strictly '[2.5.2]'
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

For more details about that implementation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints
This should solve your issue.